# asp.net identity tables location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm working on mvc5 project which is using asp.net identity for membership provider.

Now, I've registered the first test user via web interface and I was expecting to see newly created tables in the db I'm using but there are no new tables created although I'm able to register/login/logout of the app.

Where are the tables for the membership provider located?

### Update

Conn string added:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TTBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TTB.csdl|res://*/TTB.ssdl|res://*/TTB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HOME-PC;initial catalog=TTB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you using default template? or have you changed the web.config connection string?

Comment: I haven't changed anything, I'm using default template and I've put a conn string to a database where I have the app data. check the updated question to see the conn string @DSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using default template then the connection strings looks like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication21-20141121113141.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication21-20141121113141;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The database files (mdf and log) can be found in your local file storage project "App_Data" folder.

**Update**

According your connection string you are using Entity Framework connection string. You can get the answer using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) article.

Check your bin folder or any application executable storage location for relevant files. There should be three files with extensions .csdl, .ssdl and .msl.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check my updated question. Btw, there is nothing in the App_Data folder. There must be some db which the app is using to store the membership data.

Comment: Do you have any local SQL server with database name called "TTB"?

Comment: Thanks for helping me to find the solution, so the app was auto creating the db in sqlexpress. I did add another conn string pointing to my db and after that the newly created users were created in the db I want to use along with the associated tables. Thanks